# phppass password with quote marks doesn't validate

Tags: php, validation, passwords, escaping

When I submit trough a form a password with a quotation mark `"`
and use:

```
$hasher = new PasswordHash(10, FALSE);
$hasher->CheckPassword($password_safe, $retrieved_password));
```

It always fails.

But if I specify the `$password_safe` as

```
$password_safe = 'myPass"word';
```

It validates correctly. How can I escape the `$password_safe` so that the validation can still be done?

Comment: I had a previous question with this but it was too long and unfocused on the real cause.

Comment: Do you have any code or docs for the PasswordHash class? What is the second parameter for? I can't see what the "FALSE" is for?

Comment: Im using http://www.openwall.com/phpass/ for the whole password system. The FALSE is if the passwords should be encoded in such a way that they work on older systems.

Comment: With which value is the validation failing? It might have something to do with having magic_quotes enabled. Try doing a var_dump over the value you're checking.

Comment: It fails with the submitted one trough the form. var_dump gives - string(19) "9]D"B4,PgqTYT9." It seems to be reporting a wrong number of characters. This one is the real password, on the question was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this problem too.

There are two ways around it. Pass the password string through either [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or better yet [`addslashes()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php).